# Creating a contact with Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

What are the prerequisites to use [Create Contact](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_post_contacts) with Microsoft Graph? Can I use it to store contacts in Azure Table Storage?

I have some 50,000 contacts in a SQL database. What service should I have to use to manage these contacts via Microsoft Graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to what @RasmusW said, the contacts APIs in Microsoft Graph store contacts to Outlook. After migrating those contacts to Graph, you would then be able to go to outlook.com/?path=/people to see the contacts. Of course, the specific place where the contacts are stored is comparatively unimportant since they are available via the API and can be read, modified, or removed from any application that can consume the API.

Comment: I have two use cases (1) Save my sports club members contact information and pictures which can be accessed by all the club members so they can know each other. More or less like a single group with less than 2000 contacts (2) Multiple groups for different sports like ping pong, basketball which can have contacts around 25,000. Which **cloud service** would you suggest and what type of account like personal or small business that I need? I prefer both UI and DB data service to manage the contacts. I can build a UI if there is not a one but the DB data service is available.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Graph is an API to access data in Azure Active Directory and Office 365. It can't be used to access another database.